# how do I display Text field to the WordPress Customizer

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display text from custom input but in vain. I'm developing a custom WordPress theme for my site. I've added the field to the Wordpress customizer, but the content of the field is not displaying on the page.

```
function prolifictheme_add_customizer_content( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'prolific_theme_text_setting_id', array(
        'title'       => __( 'General Settings', 'prolific-theme' ),
        'priority'    => 30,
        'description' => __( 'Customize the layout of your site homepage', 'prolific-theme' )
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'prolific_theme_text_setting_id', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'default' => 'Text Goes Here',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
      ) );
      
      $wp_customize->add_control( 'prolific_theme_text_setting_id', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'section' => 'prolific_theme_text_setting_id', // Add a default or your own section
        'label' => __( 'Main Banner Title' ),
        'description' => __( 'Enter title of not more than 35 Words.' ),
      ) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'prolifictheme_add_customizer_content' );
```

**Display Text**

```
<h1><?php echo get_theme_mod( 'prolific_theme_text_setting_id' ); ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked out of the box. Where did you put the text? Insert it to the bottom of the `header.php` and you will see it. I think your are searching in the wrong template for the result.